# How to create custom component with an input in Angular and bind it to a form?

Tags: angular, forms, input, angular-forms

Lets say we have something like this

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <rc-some-component ngModel name="someComponent"></rc-some-component>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input ngModel type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
</form>
```

And the component for rc-some-component is:

```
<div>
 //...some html
<input ngModel name="someComponent" type="file" class="d-none" (change)="onUploadImage()" />
</div>
```

When I try to check the data which is sent on onSubmit I only get the data from fname. That means I cannot get data from an input which is inside rc-some-component. How can I try to solve such an issue?
Should I create something like ControlValueAccesor?

I only want to have an access to the input data (from this custom component) while invoking onSubmit (so then I am able to check it in this.formName.value)

Comment: If you wanted to go with Reactive Forms, check the Control Value Accessor, allows you to turn any component in a FormControl : https://sreyaj.dev/custom-form-controls-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the ControlValueAccessor interface, and maybe even the Validator interface if you are interested in adding validations.

I wrote an [article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-custom-form-controls-nested-form-groups-made-easy-2ac09e91cf67?sk=06cf6f37eeeae34b8f02fd6c5080f759) about custom form controls you can check.

I also created this [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-form-controls-demo) that does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Would be really nice if you also add a bit of summary here. That article url leads to a signup page of a private "member only" website.

Comment: @SalemOuerdani I updated the link with a friend-link. Now you can access it without being a member. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution if you are building a form with FormGroup and FormControls

First on your child component you need to pack the input with `<div [formGroup]="nameOfFG">`, on your input you need to set attribute `formControl="nameOfFC'`.

In your Class the only thing you need to do is provide @Input attributes. In this case, you need to `@Input nameOfFG:FormGroup` and `@Input nameOfFC:string` . Then, in parent component.html you need to input these values - your `nameOfFG` and `nameOfFC`. The form needs to be in [], because you will bind it from your component.

`<custom-component [nameOfFG]="fromGroup" nameOfFC="formControl"></custom-component>`

Then, in parent Class just initialize formgroup in `ngOnInit()` with the formControl you are using.

If you still want to go the other way around, look at EventEmitter. Basically on childcomponent, EventEmitter will be called when input changes, that is exported through `@Output` , which can be then used to change your variable in your parent class -

`<custom-component (event)="changeYourVariable()"></custom-component>`